The "end" event of a Readable stream is not working
I created an Azure function that reads an encrypted file from Azure Blob Storage, decrypts it using the AES256 algorithm, and stores the decrypted file back in Azure Blob Storage with a different file name. The first 16 bytes of the file are used as the initialization vector (IV) for decryption.
Here's a summary of what I am doing:

Reading the encrypted file from Azure Blob Storage.
Extracting the first 16 bytes as the IV.
Decrypting the remaining bytes of the file.
Storing the decrypted file back to Azure Blob Storage.

However, I encountered an issue where the 'end' event on the decryptedStream is not triggered. The 'readable' event is triggered, and chunks are read into the filedata buffer, but the 'end' event never fires, preventing me from completing the file upload. According to the Node.js documentation, the 'end' event should be triggered once all data has been read from the stream: https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#readablereadsize.
Here's the relevant part of my code:
const { BlobServiceClient, StorageSharedKeyCredential } = require("@azure/storage-blob");
const { app } = require('@azure/functions');
const crypto = require('crypto');
const stream = require('stream');

app.http('Blob-Decrypt', {
    methods: ['GET', 'POST'],
    authLevel: 'anonymous',
    handler: async (request, context) => {
        context.log(`Http function processed request for url "${request.url}"`);

        const accountName = request.query.get('accountName') || await request.text();
        const accountKey = request.query.get('accountKey') || await request.text();
        const containerName = request.query.get('containerName') || await request.text();
        const blobName = request.query.get('blobName') || await request.text();
        const decryptedBlobName = request.query.get('decryptedBlobName') || await request.text();

        let error = [];
        if (!accountName) error.push("accountName is not set.");
        if (!accountKey) error.push("accountKey is not set.");
        if (!containerName) error.push("containerName is not set.");
        if (!blobName) error.push("blobName is not set.");
        if (!decryptedBlobName) error.push("decryptedBlobName is not set.");

        if (error.length > 0) {
            return { body: JSON.stringify({ errors: error }) };
        } else {
            const IVLength = 16;
            const sharedKeyCredential = new StorageSharedKeyCredential(accountName, accountKey);
            const blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(`https://${accountName}.blob.core.windows.net`, sharedKeyCredential);
            const containerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(containerName);

            try {
                const blobClient = containerClient.getBlobClient(blobName);
                const downloadResponse = await blobClient.download();
                const downloadStream = downloadResponse.readableStreamBody;

                let initVectBuffer = Buffer.alloc(IVLength);
                let bytesRead = 0;
                const dataStream = new stream.PassThrough();
                let fileHasData = false;

                await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    downloadStream.on('data', (chunk) => {
                        if (bytesRead < IVLength) {
                            const bytesToCopy = Math.min(IVLength - bytesRead, chunk.length);
                            chunk.copy(initVectBuffer, bytesRead, 0, bytesToCopy);
                            bytesRead += bytesToCopy;

                            if (bytesRead === IVLength) {
                                console.log('Initialization Vector:', initVectBuffer);
                                const remainingData = chunk.slice(bytesToCopy);
                                if (remainingData.length > 0) fileHasData = true;
                                dataStream.push(remainingData);
                            }
                        } else {
                            if (chunk.length > 0) fileHasData = true;
                            dataStream.push(chunk);
                        }
                    });

                    downloadStream.on('end', () => {
                        if (initVectBuffer.length === 0) {
                            console.log('Initialization vector not found.');
                            reject(new Error("Initialization vector not found."));
                        }
                        console.log('Initialization Vector:', initVectBuffer);
                        resolve();
                    });

                    downloadStream.on('error', (error) => reject(error));
                });

                const password = "TestPassword@123";
                const cipherKey = crypto.createHash('sha256').update(password).digest('base64').substring(0, 32);
                const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes256', cipherKey, initVectBuffer);

                const decryptedStream = new stream.PassThrough();

                if (fileHasData === true) {
                    dataStream.pipe(decipher).pipe(decryptedStream);

                    const filedata = [];
                    await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                        decryptedStream.on('readable', async () => {
                            console.log('readable event emitted');
                            let chunk;
                            while (null !== (chunk = decryptedStream.read())) {
                                filedata.push(chunk);
                                console.log('receiving file data');
                            }
                        });

                        decryptedStream.on('end', async () => {
                            console.log('end triggered');
                            const content = Buffer.concat(filedata).toString();
                            if (content.length > 0) {
                                const blockBlobClient = containerClient.getBlockBlobClient(decryptedBlobName);
                                await blockBlobClient.uploadData(content);
                                console.log("decryption completed and uploaded");
                            } else {
                                console.log("File content empty, unable to upload.");
                            }
                            resolve();
                        });

                        decryptedStream.on('error', (err) => {
                            console.error('[decryptedStream] An error occurred:', err);
                            reject(err);
                        });

                        decryptedStream.on('close', () => {
                            console.log('decryptedStream has been closed.');
                        });
                    });
                } else {
                    const blockBlobClient = containerClient.getBlockBlobClient(decryptedBlobName);
                    await blockBlobClient.upload('', 0, {
                        blobHTTPHeaders: { blobContentType: 'text/csv' }
                    });
                }

                return { body: 'done' };

            } catch (error) {
                context.error("Error:", error);
                return { status: 500, body: 'Internal Server Error. Error message = ' + error };
            }
        }
    }
});


I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Why is the 'end' event not triggered? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
